# Aggregating RSS Items in Java

Tags: java, rss, aggregation

I'm trying to build a polling service in Java that checks for updates from a RSS feed.

On detecting new items, it should only send new items further on in the system.

Is there an API that does this or would I have to do the comparison checks myself?

At the moment, my poller just returns what it currently sees causing duplicates in my system.

Comment: API for comparison? like `obj1.equals(obj2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to what you require is available in Informa

"Poller module is intended to provide convenient services for background polling of channel changes"

http://informa.sourceforge.net/poller.html

Answer (score 1):

Sun have an RSS Utilities library that was built for creating feeds. However it also includes a useful RSS parser that I am using to do a similar thing.

You can download the library from here (scroll down to the bottom for more information on the parser):

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/rss_utilities/

To check for new items, just get the GUID and compare it with GUIDs for existing items.

```
// Create an RSS Parser
RssParser parser = RssParserFactory.createDefault();

// Parse the feed
Rss rss = parser.parse( new URL( YOUR_FEED ) );

// Get the channel
Channel channel = rss.getChannel();

// Get the items
Collection<Item> items = channel.getItems();

// Loop for each item
for ( Item item : items )
{
  // Get the GUID
  Guid guid = item.getGuid();

  // Loop for each of the previously seen GUIDs and compare
}
```

Comment: This is the actual download link: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/rss_utilities/rss_utils_1.1.zip

Answer (score 0):

Well i am new to java... but here is the simple code that I tried and works well. Instead of reading the RSS from a specific website, I read the RSS from local directory. Use Informa API available at http://informa.sourceforge.net/

```
public class Read_UpdateRSS implements de.nava.informa.utils.poller.PollerObserverIF {

public static void main(String[] args) {

try {

        File in = new File("/home/RSSFeed/rssfeed.xml");

        ChannelBuilder build = new ChannelBuilder();

        Channel channel = (Channel) FeedParser.parse(build,in);
        System.out.println("Description:" + channel.getDescription());
        System.out.println("Title:" + channel.getTitle());

        // Magic of polling starts here. polling is done every 10 minutes

        Poller poll = new Poller();
        PollerObserverIF observer = new Read_UpdateRSS();
        poll.addObserver(observer);
        poll.registerChannel(channel, 10 * 60 * 1000);

        for(Object x: channel.getItems()){

            Item anItem = (Item) x;
            System.out.println(anItem.getTitle() + "-");
            System.out.println(anItem.getDescription());
    }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

@Override
public void channelChanged(ChannelIF arg0) {}

@Override
public void channelErrored(ChannelIF arg0, Exception arg1) {}

@Override
public void itemFound(ItemIF item, ChannelIF channel) {

    System.out.println("new item found");
    channel.addItem(item);
}

@Override
public void pollFinished(ChannelIF channel) {
    System.out.println("Finished polling with " +  channel.getItems().size() + " items in the channel");

}

@Override
public void pollStarted(ChannelIF channel) {
    System.out.println("Started polling with " + channel.getItems().size() + " items in the channel");

}
```

}